# Doxygen: is there a difference between `\link` and `\ref`?

Tags: doxygen

Here is the documentation for `\link` (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdlink) and `\ref` (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref). They seem to be effectively the same. Are they the same?

Answer (score 4):

The commands `\ref` and `link ... \endlink` are nearly the same, there are some subtle difference, especially in respect to the markdown handling and the fact that the optional text after a `\ref` has to be between double quotes and as such follows the rules for string handling.

Consider the folwing example (with default doxygen settings and running with the current doxygen version 1.9.7):

```
/// \file

/// the docu
///
/// - \ref x
/// - \ref x "text"
/// - \ref x "\b text"
/// - \ref x "`text`"
/// - \link x \endlink
/// - \link x text \endlink
/// - \link x \b text \endlink
/// - \link x `text` \endlink
int x;
```

the result is:

[image]

note the differences when using a backtick (`` ` ``)